# Topological S-matrix as an operator in the graphical calculus

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, spin-models

My question comes from the following classic paper by Kitaev:

- [Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438v3) (arXiv link)

In Appendix E (pg 86), Kitaev introduces a diagram operator $S_z$ which acts on a splitting vertex in the Hilbert space $V^{bz}_b$. You should then be able to preform the inner product with a conjugate vertex in order to create a closed graph with matrix elements $(S_z)_{ab}$ where $(S_1)_{ab}$ is the usual modular S-matrix. However when I try this calculation I always end up with additional normalization constants, could anyone explain the correct normalization scheme for such a calculation?